# 90 Columns in a MySQL database table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to find an optimal solution to my problem.

Basically I have a form that will consist of mostly checkboxes the form however the form will have some 60-90 checkboxes. And I will have a few of these forms so the problem I have is how to create this in most generic or simplistic way so I do not have to create each form for each table by hand.

My solution was to simply create a table the down side here is that I get a table with some 90 columns which is pretty messy to view in any client and has a little impact on performance as the table grows but not that much since most field types are tinyint.

In my Models I define a schema basically an array:

```
$schema = array(
  'column_name' => array('checkbox(input field type)', 'label')
);

public function getSchema()
{
 $this->schema['column_name]['value'] = $this->column_name;
 // .. Now I have to type this 100 times by hand..
}
```

This now allows me to just have 1 form and easily generate all the fields

```
    <form>
     @foreach($schema as $field => $attrs)
      @if($attrs[0] == 'checkbox')
       <input type="checkbox" name="{{ $field }}" value="{{ $attrs['value'] }} {{ ($attrs['value'] == 1) ? 'checked' : '' }}>{{ $attrs[1] }}
      @elseif($attrs[0] == 'text')
       ...
      @endif
     @endforeach

</form>
```

So it's a pretty elegant solution however I don't really gain that much if I have to define each field in getSchema() function for their value or that I must define schema array first which ends up being as if I defined two forms anyway.

I think I found somewhat solution here but don't fully know how to get rid of the manually defining the schema array and the method.

One of the ideas I had was to just have one field for value and define local variables in my model populate these when doing IO and serialize the object and store it but this seems wastefully and bad practice.

Comment: Store your data as JSON

Comment: @cmorrissey Noooooo, that will make searching / filtering a nightmare.

Comment: No, store it in a *normalized* relational database

Comment: serializing is bad option

Comment: 90 columns is architecture fault... something like [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) can be helpful for you. Or some noSQL solution.

Comment: Want you to see a webpage with 90 checkboxes in other applications? On Facebook, or on SO for example? I'm not... Need another solution, I think..

Comment: kellax, that would be a spreadsheet, NOT a database table!

Comment: If just check boxes a table of forms (one row per form), table of form questions (one row per form per question) and a table of form answers (one row per form question per person filling the form in - and if check boxes you only need to store a row if they checked the box as no entry can just be an unchecked box).

Answer (score 6):

just create a new table with 4 columns

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id + entity_id + form_key + form_value
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This way all your values will be indexed and it's easier to manage.

Comment: That will also make searching/filtering a nightmare.

Comment: I actually like this idea. To define the field types but IO would be more complex then was hoping to simplify it. Would require me to rework the database tables but this is an option I put a pin in.

Comment: @James - please give us also an example. I don't see how this solution could constitute a problem on searching / indexing.

Comment: @cfv1000 try to select all the entities that have checkboxes 7, 16, 17, 24 and 25 checked.  Or display a report of *n* entities and the values of all their checkboxes.  You have to join to the EAV table for each column, and there are 90 of them.

Comment: no there are not. All those 90 columns will be reduced. You have 2 tables: one for the main info, and one for the checkbox info. You have only one join. 
Let us make this to be an example like product => filter
We have table product (id, name, price)

and table filter (id, product, key, value)

making joins like this is fast and easy by product.id = filter.product

Comment: I was assuming that filter would have 90 rows per 1 row in product, as there are 90 "keys".  Is that not what you are suggesting?

Comment: SELECT product.id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(filter.key, ":", filter.value)) filters from product LEFT JOIN filter ON filter.product = product.id GROUP BY product.id;

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ product + filters                                              +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1       + filter1:value1,filter2:value2...filter90:value90     +
+ 2       + filter1:value1,filter2:value2...filter90:value90     +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Answer (score 4):

checkbox -> 2 options = 1 bit.

one integer has 32 bits. 
one long integer has even more.

you can store your checkboxes into a bitmask. thus storing 100 checkboxes into 2-4 table columns. you can search, select, and update easily since mysql provides bit operations easily.

on the downside, any work with a database administration (e.g. phpmyadmin) and direct access to the database is brutal.

Comment: How he can select all entities with selected option #56 later?

Comment: If option 56 is mapped to field_2, bit 4, then it would be `select * from table where field_2 & 8 = 1`  8 is equal to `2^(4 - 1)`

Comment: I don't understand how that works over four columns. Can you point me to an explanation.

Comment: While efficient in storage (and I have done similar things with long bit strings in mainframe systems), I am not sure it is a worthwhile gain in storage compared to the difficulty reading the values.

Comment: In my comment above I made a mistake in the query -> `select * from table where field_2 & 8 = 8`